# Conditional probability multiple conditions

Tags: conditional-probability

I have a question about conditional probability. Is it true that $P(A|B|C)$ equal to $P((A|B)|C)$ equal to $P(A|(B|C))$?

Comment: What does $P(A|(B|C))$ *mean*?  Or rather, what does $(B|C)$ mean?  Surely it isn't a probability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are all identical.

If even one of A, B, or C is true, then all of the statements should evaluate to true. You can test that out for yourself. One of the OR's will become true, which makes the whole expression true.